# File Parsing using sscanf in C

Tags: c, file, parsing

I am trying to read from a file and essentially split each line into 2 strings. However, my current code is giving me a seg fault.

```
char* lhsdata = (char *)malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
char* rhsdata = (char *)malloc(15 * sizeof(char));
while(fgets(line,sizeof line,filePtr)){
        if (line[0] == '\n') break;
        //Do operations on each line
        sscanf(line, "%s %s\n", lhsdata, rhsdata);
        printf("%s %s\n", lhsdata, rhsdata);
        rhsdata[strlen(rhsdata)-1] = '\0';
}
```

The file looks like this

```
add $s1,$s0,$s0
add $t2,$s0,$s5
addi $t4,$s3,70
```

The last line of the file is empty

Tried playing around with the lhsdata and rhsdata but to no avail. Im pretty stubborn so I want to know how to fix this issue using sscanf (i know there are other options).

Comment: What is `rhsdata[strlen(rhsdata)-1] = '\0'` supposed to do?  What if `rhsdata` is `""` (a zero-length string...)?  You're also never checking if `sscanf()` actually scans anything...

Comment: Your code works on my machine. Please supply a _complete_ example (and test that example yourself), to rule out the possibility that the problem is elsewhere in your code. UB sometimes moves in mysterious ways.

Comment: I'm particularly interested in the definition of `line`. It should be a (sufficiently long) array. If you defined it as a pointer (like you did with `lhsdata` and `rhsdata`), then that may well explain the segfault (due to the use of `sizeof`).

Comment: I would prefer char c; sscanf(line,"%s%s%c", lhsdata, rhsdata, &c); And char lhsdata[32], rhsdata[32];

Comment: Try to create  a [mcve]. Doing that will greatly increase your chances of getting help quickly.

Comment: Check the return value of sscanf.  Doing so will at least give you more info about where things are going wrong.  Never use `\n` in a scanf format string (it is the same as a space), and only use spaces where they are needed (before a `%c` or `%n` or `%[` or bare character, never anywhere else)